# Updating database data with form in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine, repository, entity

I have a User entity on my Symfony File, i've tried to update some data (username & email) with a form but it seems i'm doing it wrong. I'm pretty new to Symfo so i think i don't do it the right way.

```php
    public function index(Request $req, ObjectManager $manager)
    {

        $user = new UserSecurity();



        $form = $this->createForm(UserUpdateType::class, $user);

        $form->handleRequest($req);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $manager->persist($user);
            $manager->flush();
        }

        return $this->render('dashboard/dashboard.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'DashboardController',
            'formUpdate' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is the most basic i've tried, in my db email field can't be null, in my form if i try to change only username and leave email as blank, it's interpred as null, so it return an error

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user_security (email, >password, validation_token, username) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params >[null, null, null, "theusernameivetyped"]:

It seems the form try to create a new User instead of updating it, i think i've something to do with the Repository but can't really find what ...

and there is my Entity:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserSecurityRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *      fields={"email"},
 *      message="L'adresse email est déjà utilisé"
 * )
 */
class UserSecurity implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Email(message="Vous devez saisir une adresse email valide")
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(min=8, minMessage="Votre mot de passe doit faire au minimum 8 caractères")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @Assert\EqualTo(propertyPath="password", message="La confirmation ne correspond pas au mot de passe")
     */
    public $confirm_password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $validation_token;

    public $confirmation_token;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $username;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getValidationToken(): ?string
    {
        return $this->validation_token;
    }

    public function setValidationToken(?string $validation_token): self
    {
        $this->validation_token = $validation_token;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return ['ROLE_USER'];
    }

    public function getSalt()
    { }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    { }

    public function setUsername(?string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

and my FormType

```php
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\UserSecurity;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class UserUpdateType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email')
            ->add('username')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => UserSecurity::class,
            'required' => false,

        ]);
    }
}
```

I expect to the current user who submit the form will see his data updated in database.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i finally deal with it alone,

```php
class DashboardController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function __invoke(Request $request): Response
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserUpdateType::class, $user)->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->em->flush();
        }

        return $this->render('dashboard/dashboard.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok for the edit, i've just tested it and it work good ! I just don't really get the difference between EntityManagerInterface that we use here, and ObjectManager that i used before . I mean, i supposed EntityManagerInterface deal with Entity :D but what is the good usage for ObjectManager ? Second point: i'm not really comfortable with magic methods, why using __invoke here ?